# How to make the new functions work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna know how to make the functions work *after* adding new texts and the delete button. I add the  new rows and the new functions (`deleteRow` and `resizeInput`) doesn't work.

```js
$('#addNew').click(function(event){
 newRow();
});
 
$('.deleteButton').click(function(){
 deleteRow($(this));
});

function newRow(){ 
 var numFilas = $('#nuevasTareas tr').length;
 $('#nuevasTareas').append('<tr><td><input type="text" id="titulo'+numFilas+'" /></td><td><input type="text" id="descripcion'+numFilas+'" /></td><td><input type = "checkbox"></input></td><td><a class="deleteButton" id="eliminar" title="Eliminar Tarea">X Eliminar</a></td></tr>');
 }

function deleteRow(thisButton){
 thisButton.parent().parent().remove();
}

function resizeInput() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
}
$('input[type="text"]')
   .keyup(resizeInput)
    .each(resizeInput);
```

Comment: Did you get any error on console? Please check in browser console

Comment: Read this: [jQuery - Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `event delegation` in this case. When you bind events using `.click`, it will bind the event only on DOM elements which were available at the moment of binding.

Instead you must use `event delegation` using `.on()` jQuery api. Here you will bind the event to parent element and delegate it to the child element.

```
$(document).on("click", '#addNew', function(event){
    newRow();
});

$(document).on("click", '.deleteButton', function(){
    deleteRow($(this));
});
```

Since you've not shared the HTML, i've used `document` as the parent element. Instead you can even use just `table` in your case as it will be the parent of `tr`.